# Send multiple results as single message with line breaks to telegram bot in PHP

Tags: php, tesseract

I'm running tesseract on images in images folder and if the OCR result has "Error occurred" text then I want to send all the pictures names with error message concatenated as a single message with lines breaks of course for each message.

With the below code I'm receiving separate messages for every single picture result.

But I want Something like as on this picture all as a single message.
[image: Example picture]

Here is my code tho;

```
$dir = "images/*.jpg";

$images = glob( $dir );

foreach( $images as $image):

$result = (new TesseractOCR($image))
->run();

$info = pathinfo($image);
$file_name =  basename($image,'.'.$info['extension']);
$Name = str_replace("_"," ", $file_name);

$msg = "Error Occurred";

if($result === $msg)
{
    $err = $Name . " - Says - ".$msg."\n";

    $apiToken = $bot_token;
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => $err
    ];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
    
}
else 
{
    

    $msg = $Name . " - Good! \n";

    echo $msg."</br>";

}

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending of the message needs to happen outside of the foreach loop

I have changed the code to collect all the errors into an array then after the loop if any errors exist, it implodes the array into a multiline string and sends the message

```
<?php

$dir = "images/*.jpg";

$images = glob($dir);

$errors = [];

foreach ($images as $image) {

    $result = (new TesseractOCR($image))
        ->run();

    $info = pathinfo($image);
    $file_name = basename($image, '.' . $info['extension']);
    $Name = str_replace("_", " ", $file_name);

    $msg = "Error Occurred";

    if ($result === $msg) {
        $errors[] = $Name . " - Says - " . $msg;
    }
    else {
        $msg = $Name . " - Good! \n";
        echo $msg . "</br>";
    }
}

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $apiToken = $bot_token;
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => implode("\n", $errors)
    ];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data));
}
```